# Regex to differentiate between sentences and chapter text

Tags: python, regex, text-segmentation

I have a (running) text with many sentences. I have a regular expression that is able to extract the sentences that are terminated by a period, question or exclamation mark. The end of a sentence must be followed by a beginning of the next sentence ( white spaces/tabs/new lines and a capital letter or number). I read a string stored in data and a call the regex.

```
basic_pat = re.compile(r"[(']?\w.+[)']?[?.!](?=\s+[A-Z\d])")
result = basic_pat.findall(data)
```

This regex seems to be working if we do not take into consideration the abbreviation cases.
In the text I may also have some chapter texts that do not end with a period. For example:

> This is the first chapter
>   Here is the first sentence. Here is the second sentence.Here ids the third sent. Here is 
>   the fourth sent...

My question is if it is possible to have one regex that reads only the chapter texts as well as a regex that reads the sentences. The chapters are loose text in a line without a period. Regular sentences may cover several lines. That is, sentences may also have text in a line without period. Is it possible to differentiate the two situations (chapter vs sentences) with regex?

Comment: Don’t forget quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems. 
>   -- Jamie Zawinski

Actually, what you should do is use *two* regular expressions (now you'll have *four* problems).

First, go through and break up the text into alternating chapter-headers and not-chapter-headings.  Then examine each not-chapter-heading for sentences, paragraphs, and what have you.

How would you break up the following:

> Visiting Leipzig, Chapter One:  Thomaskirchhof St.
>
> The Bach Museum is on Thomaskirchhof opposite St. Thomas's Church.
>   van Beethoven doesn't have a
>   museum anywhere in Leipzig.

Processing natural language is devilishly difficult.  God did a thorough job when He destroyed the Tower of Babel.

Comment: You *do* use regexes for this; the difference is you don’t use *only* regexes.  You are going to have to use machine learning to model likely sentence endings to sort out your streets form your saints.  Also, the “van” in Beethoven’s name is spurious.  Look it up. No well-formed English sentence is permitted to start with a lowercase letter. However, that doesn’t help you parse things that don’t meet that definition.

Comment: @tchrist -- you mean, on Wikipedia: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_van_Beethoven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_van_Beethoven) ?